# variable not passed to predicate method in ANTLR

Tags: antlr

The java code generated from ANTLR is one rule, one method in most times. But for the following rule:

```
switchBlockLabels[ITdcsEntity _entity,TdcsMethod _method,List<IStmt> _preStmts]
    :   ^(SWITCH_BLOCK_LABEL_LIST switchCaseLabel[_entity, _method, _preStmts]* switchDefaultLabel? switchCaseLabel*)
    ;
```

it generates a submethod named `synpred125_TreeParserStage3_fragment()`, in which mehod `switchCaseLabel(_entity, _method, _preStmts)` is called:

```
synpred125_TreeParserStage3_fragment(){
    ......
    switchCaseLabel(_entity, _method, _preStmts);//variable not found error        
    ......
}

switchBlockLabels(ITdcsEntity _entity,TdcsMethod _method,List<IStmt> _preStmts){
    ......
    synpred125_TreeParserStage3_fragment();
    ......
}
```

The problem is `switchCaseLabel` has parameters and the parameters come from the parameters of `switchBlockLabels()` method, so "variable not found error" occurs.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see any variables. Please post your grammar, or if it's big, strip it down so that it demonstrates your problem without needing to wade through too much code. Thanks. Also note that it is not ANTLRWorks that generates the code, it's ANTLR itself. ANTLRWorks is just an editor that makes use of ANTLR.

Comment: @BartKiers, I've described my problem in more details.Hope for your help.Thanks.

Comment: thanks, although not as much information as I hoped for. My answer now assumes you also have `options {backtrack=true;}` in your grammar. If not, then you'll have to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) before I'm going to be able to look any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you've enabled global backtracking in your grammar like this:

```java
options {
  backtrack=true;
}
```

in which case you can't pass parameters to ambiguous rules. In order to communicate  between ambiguous rules when you have enabled global backtracking, you must use *rule scopes*. The "predicate-methods" *do* have access to *rule scopes* variables.

---

### A demo

Let's say we have this ambiguous grammar:

```java
grammar Scope;

options { 
  backtrack=true;
}

parse
  :  atom+ EOF
  ;

atom
  :  numberOrName+
  ;

numberOrName
  :  Number
  |  Name
  ;

Number : '0'..'9'+;
Name   : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
Space  : ' ' {skip();};
```

*(for the record, the `atom+` and `numberOrName+` make it ambiguous)*

If you now want to pass information between the `parse` and `numberOrName` rule, say an integer `n`, something like this will fail (which is the way you tried it):

```java
grammar Scope;

options { 
  backtrack=true;
}

parse
@init{int n = 0;}
  :  (atom[++n])+ EOF
  ;

atom[int n]
  :  (numberOrName[n])+
  ;

numberOrName[int n]
  :  Number {System.out.println(n + " = " + $Number.text);}
  |  Name   {System.out.println(n + " = " + $Name.text);}
  ;

Number : '0'..'9'+;
Name   : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
Space  : ' ' {skip();};
```

In order to do this using *rule scopes*, you could do it like this:

```java
grammar Scope;

options { 
  backtrack=true;
}

parse
scope{int n;         /* define the scoped variable          */ }
@init{$parse::n = 0; /* important: initialize the variable! */ }
  :  atom+ EOF
  ;

atom
  :  numberOrName+
  ;

numberOrName /* increment and print the scoped variable from the parse rule */
  :  Number {System.out.println(++$parse::n + " = " + $Number.text);} 
  |  Name   {System.out.println(++$parse::n + " = " + $Name.text);}
  ;

Number : '0'..'9'+;
Name   : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
Space  : ' ' {skip();};
```

---

### Test

If you now run the following class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String src = "foo 42 Bar 666";
    ScopeLexer lexer = new ScopeLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(src));
    ScopeParser parser = new ScopeParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

you will see the following being printed to the console:

```
1 = foo
2 = 42
3 = Bar
4 = 666
```

---

### P.S.

I don't know what language you're parsing, but enabling global backtracking is usually overkill and can have quite an impact on the performance of your parser. Computer languages often are ambiguous in just a few cases. Instead of enabling global backtracking, you really should look into adding syntactic predicates, or enabling backtracking on those rules that are ambiguous. See [The Definitive ANTLR Reference](http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference) for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much.After reading your answer,I've solved my problem.Also ,thanks for your suggestion.